# Несколько форм на лендинге как к ним обращаться из js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

На Лендинге 3 формы, при заполнении которых пользователь должен получать разные сообщения об отправке когда будет `submit`, реализовано вместо `Alert` через `MagnificPopup`. Но получает сообщение одно и то же сообщение. **JS** обращается ко всем формам на сайте. Подскажите способ реализации...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //E-mail Ajax Send
  $("form").submit(function() { //??? FORM ???
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Thank you!");
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Done Functions
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, со всех форм запрос уходит на один и тот же mail.php, в котором уже происходит выбор, какое именно письмо отправить.
Если так, то как вариант - в каждую форму добавляем hidden input, в нём записываем тип письма (напр., `<input type="hidden" name="email_type" value="email_1">`), а в mail.php уже берём `$_POST['email_type']` и смотрим, к какому типу оно относится.

Comment: да все верно, есть скрытые поля и все корректно приходит, скорее всего я неправильно изложил мысль. Проблема вот в чем: есть формы: заказ звонка, заказ(основной) ,получить предложение. С моей стороны все принимается и с какой формы - видно. Но как сделать так чтобы всплывающее окно пользователю вылетало разное? Типа: спасибо за заказ! или мы вам перезвоним! Как обратиться напрямую к разным формам?

Comment: @EalisBoyko, довольно просто. В скрипте mail.php после отправки письма, в том же блоке условия, что и сама отправка, делаете что-то вроде `echo "Спасибо за заказ!"` (текст подставляете в каждом блоке свой), а в js уже добавьте `.done(function(data)` и выводите текст из data в попап через append, например.